# Can not direct to detail.java class in android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to post cnic and if cnic matches and status return is 1 then direct to detail.java otherwise stay it Main activity.java
I can not go to detail.java . can some1 tell me what is wrong with my code

**Main activity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText cnic;
String url = "https://Homeweb.com/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cnic=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);


}

public void Signin(View v) {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitArrayAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayAPI.class);
//    Call<List<LoginModel>> call = service.getDetails();
    service.login( cnic.getText().toString(), new  Callback<LoginModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<LoginModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }

        public void success(LoginModel model, Response response) {

            finish();

            startActivity(getIntent());
            cnic.setText("");

            if (model.getStatus().equals("1")) {  //login Success

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login In SuccessFully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Detail.class);

                startActivity(i);

            } else if (model.getStatus().equals("0"))  // login failure

            {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid UserName/Pass ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }


    });

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**RetrofitArrayAPI.interface**

```
       public interface RetrofitArrayAPI {


   * Retrofit get annotation with our URL
   * And our method that will return us details of student.
   */

   @POST("/Login.php")
   void login(@Field("M_cnic") String cnic, Callback<LoginModel> cb);

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
startActivity(getIntent());
```

That makes no sense.  It would just relaunch the current activity.  If you want to go to another Activity, you have to create a new Intent for the Activity you wish to go to.  Then you might make another intent later and start it?  I think you need to go through your code and really think about what you're trying to do and what each line does.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem

```
 Call<Student> call = service.getDetails(M_cnic);


    call.enqueue(new Callback<Student>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Student> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            try {
                 String check;
                text_status_1.setText("StudentId  :  " + response.body().getC_name());
                         //text_status_1.setText("Status  :  " + StudentData.get(i). getC_name());
                         //text_city_2.setText("city  : " + StudentData.get(i).getCity());
                           check=response.body().getStatus();
                if(check.equals("1"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login In SuccessFully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Detail.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putString("M_cnic", M_cnic);

                    startActivity(i);


                }

                else if (check.equals("0"))  // login failure

                {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid UserName/Pass ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }






            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Suggestion: `getStatus` could return a boolean